# is it better to use a Dictionary or Class to pass values to a method?

Tags: c#

Is it better to use a `Dictonary` or `Class` in the following scenario:

I have a method called `GetEmailTemplateFilePath(Dictonary<string,object> emailPath);` which currently takes `Dictionary key/value pairs` that basically build the path to the template, so when I pass that into the method it returns the correct template.  Is this fine or would it be better to use a `Class` like `EmailPath`:

```
public class EmailPath
{
   public string Root {get;set;}
   public string Action {get;set;}

}
```

and then it would be `GetEmailTemplateFilePath(EmailPath emailPath);`

Comment: Are the path components predefined? If they are, use an object. (Or just several regular parameters.)

Comment: Are you using a Dictionary because the Key mest be unique?   If so that should answer your question.

Comment: @millimoose - some are predefined, but some are determined at runtime dependent on what action happened and what user ran it.

Comment: @Blam - I don't quite understand your question.  Don't dictionaries require you have have unique keys anyways?  If I need a different value, I just replace one of the values for one of the keys with a different one.

Comment: @xaisoft That sounds like you really want several classes (one per action?) that implement a shared interface.

Comment: @millimoose - So correct me if I am wrong, you think I am using the Dictionary for too much and I should break it up into several classes.

Comment: @xaisoft Yes. Dictionaries are appropriate when all their values have the same meaning. So if you had a dictionary of usernames and email addresses, that would be appropriate. But if the keys of a dictionary are really fields of a data structure, you should probably use an actual data structure. (Or, as the case may be, several, and use polymorphism to take care of the different properties for each action.)

Comment: Exactly -1.  Dictionary requires a unique key.  A collection of EmailPath does not.

Answer (score 2):

A class is better as it is more expressive and more extensible.  The intent of what you are doing is much clearer using a class.